# How to enable http request/response logs in hadoop gcs connector?

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc, google-data-api

As per the documentation https://googleapis.github.io/google-http-java-client/http-transport.html
I created one file named logging.properties with content

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
# Set up logging of HTTP requests and responses (uncomment “level” to show)
com.google.api.client.http.level = ALL
```

and running the command

```
bin/hadoop fs  -Djava.util.logging.config.file='<path>/logging.properties' -ls gs://gcs-mthakur-bucket/
```

but I am not getting any http wire logs. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions on how to enable GCS API wire logs using `hadoop fs` CLI are documented in the [GCS connector troubleshooting documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/9eab9b3cb0f3901303128881312f41a4173779be/gcs/INSTALL.md#troubleshooting-the-installation):

```
$ cat <<EOF >"/tmp/google-logging.properties"
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = CONFIG
com.google.level = CONFIG
EOF

$ export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/google-logging.properties"

$ hadoop --loglevel debug fs -ls gs://<some-bucket>
```